# Find PDC Emulator role holder

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

Is there a way locate the server with the PDCE role using VBScript?  I know I can use an NSLOOKUP and capture its output

```
nslookup -type=all _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.mydomain.com
```

I want to use VBScript wihout calling external programs and it must run on a Windows 7 workstation (32 and 64bit) without additional software!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NETDOM.EXE tool on server

```
netdom query /domain:DOM fsmo
```

Where DOM is my Netbios domain name

You can use DSQUERY.EXE tool

```
dsquery server -hasfsmo schema
```

(the five roles are: schema, rid, name, infr and pdc)

[Determining FSMO Role Holders](http://www.petri.co.il/determining_fsmo_role_holders.htm) seems to be a good source

---

(Edited)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1082221/ddbc236610f743e06b9833f2502dca55bd3bed42) is an example of VBScript doing that using ADSI.

Comment: These commands are not available on a Windows 7 workstation (although I should have put that in my original post) and are also not vbscript so, not much help.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: (Edited)I use my 14 of july (french national day) to write an ADSI VBScrip doing that.

Comment: It has some hardcoded stuff in it which may prevent it working in my situation, such as the DC to run the query, but I might be able to make use of it with some modifications. I'll report back when I've has some time to look into it in more detail... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the PDC Master you must query the fSMORoleOwner attribute on the partition corresponding to your domain.

Here is a sample VBS (visit http://adcoding.com/ for more information):

```
Set objDomDn = GetObject("LDAP://dc=concorp,dc=contoso,dc=com")
strfsmoRoleOwner = objDomDn.Get("fsmoRoleOwner")

Set objPDCfsmo = GetObject("LDAP://" &  strfsmoRoleOwner)
Set objPDCfsmoParent = GetObject(objPDCfsmo.Parent)

Wscript.Echo  objPDCfsmoParent.Get("dnsHostName")
```